# Stack Smashing Detected C++ in Card game

Tags: c++, pointers

So im programming a poker game (because im bored) and just setting out the classes and testing it works as i go along and its working perfectly BUT suddenly i add some new code to have an actual deck instead of infinite random cards and i just get this error

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is from a g++ compiler on mint 19.3 cinnamon

I looked at other questions that are similar to mine but they seem to be about large amounts of data and i dont really see how thats in my program.

If someone could help out or at least explain the error message that would be great

-thanks

/  my code  /

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


class Card{
public:
    static Card* deck;
    static int current;
    char house;
    char value;

    void setTo(Card c){
        house = c.house;
        value = c.value;
    }

    void random(){
        setTo(*(deck + current));
        current++;
    }

    void print(){

        switch (value){
            case 11:
                cout << "jack";
                break;
            case 12:
                cout << "queen";
                break;
            case 13:
                cout << "king";
                break;
            case 14:
                cout << "ace";
                break;
            default:
                cout << (int)value;
                break;
        }

        cout << " of ";
        switch (house){
            case 0:
                cout << "spades";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "clubs";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "hearts";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "diamonds";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "there has been an error, the house is invalid";
                break;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    static void CreateDeck(){
        Card cs[52];
        deck = &cs[0];

        int k;
        for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<14;j++){
                k =  (i*13) + j;
                deck[k].house = i;
                deck[k].value = (j+1);
            }
        }
    }

    static void ShuffleDeck()
        int j,k;
        Card t;
        for(int i = 0;i<52;i++){
            j = rand() % 52;
            k = rand() % 52;
            t.setTo(*(deck+j));
            (*(deck+j)).setTo(*(deck+k));
            (*(deck+k)).setTo(t);
        }
    }
};

class Player{
    public:
        int chips;
        Card* hand;
        string pName;

        void initialize(string n){
            chips = 1000;
            pName = n;
            Card cs[2];
            hand = &cs[0];
        }

        void print(){
            cout << "player: " << pName << endl;
            cout << "    ";
            (*hand).print();
            cout << "    ";
            (*(hand +1)).print();
            cout << "    " << chips << " chips" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

        void deal(){
            (*hand).random();
            (*(hand+1)).random();
        }

};

class Game{
    public:
        int pot;
        Card* deck;

        void initialize(){
            pot = 0;
            Card c[5];
            deck = &c[0];
        }
};

Card* Card::deck = NULL;
int Card::current = 0;

int main()
{

    srand (time(NULL));
    Card::CreateDeck();
    Card::ShuffleDeck();
    Card b[2];
    b[0].random();
    b[1].random();

    b[0].print();
    b[1].print();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `deck = &cs[0];` <- `cs` is a local variable and it get destroyed at the end of the function. After that `deck` points at invalid memory. Use a `std::vector` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: The error is because you use `deck` even though it's a dangling pointer. That's UB and anything can happen.

Comment: @super, this is not the answer section.

Comment: Excellent reading: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here in `createDeck`:

```
    Card cs[52];
    deck = &cs[0];
```

You have `deck` point to a local variable in the function.  When the function exits the variable goes out of scope, so attempting to dereference `deck` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simplest fix is to dynamically allocate an array using `new`:

```
deck = new Card[52];
```

And have a cleanup routine to `delete []` the memory.

A better way would be to define it as a `std::vector`:

```
class Card{
public:
    static std::vector<Card> deck;

...

std::vector<Card> Card::deck(52);
```

This gives you better control over the memory.  You will however need to change any explicit pointer arithmetic and derefernce to array subscript notation (i.e `*(deck + x)` --> `deck[x]` since `std::vector` doesn't support these operators.

Also in `createDesk`, you're going off the end of the array/vector here:

```
for(int j = 0;j<14;j++){
```

You want one less:

```
for(int j = 0;j<13;j++){
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Was working on the "better" solution.  Added mention of adding a cleanup routine for the `new` case and gave option to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at regarding `j` ... that's not used for array indexing?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 `*(deck+j)` won't work if `deck` is changed to `std::vector` because it doesn't define `operator+(int)`, at least not on gcc 4.8.5.

Comment: I'm talking about your complaint regarding the loop counter `j`. It's possible the 13 instead of 14 _was_ a mistake (I haven't tried to decode what that particular magic number actually means), but I can't see how this counts as "going off the end of the array/vector"

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Using `14` instead of `13` (i.e. the number of cards in a suit) causes the inner loop to execute 56 times but `desk` only has 52 elements.

Comment: *gave option to use `std::vector`* – That's not an "option", using a container ist the only sensible thing to do!

Comment: @TedLyngmo https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-only-sensible-thing-mean-in-this-phrase

Comment: @J.Doe Ok, one opinion mandates it - Just to clarify, I agree, using a container **is** the sensible thing to do.

Comment: If the size is known at compile time, and the logic doesn't expect for size to, ever, change, `std::array` is better option, than `std::vector` (IMO).

Comment: @J.Doe Using a vector for this isn't all that sensible

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I didn't say "vector", I said "container".

Comment: @J.Doe You were directly responding to a quote about vector, and said that it should be "the only sensible thing to do" rather than "an option", whereas in fact the opposite is true. Shrug.